# How to display .txt file in ASP.NET MVC AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Content file.txt:

Line 1.      Hello world!!

Line 2.      Ajax's fantastic.

At index.cshtml. What i want is:

```
<div id='ViewFile'>
Line 1.      Hello world!!
Line 2.      Ajax's fantastic.
</div>
```

In fact, I got:

```
<div id='ViewFile'>
Line 1.Hello world!!Line 2.Ajax's fantastic.
</div>
```

Please let me know how to load original file.txt into div-id='ViewFile'

Comment: use `</br>` for new line

Comment: what about "\t" (tab). I mean spacing

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<div>` use `<pre>`, this tag *pre*serves the line breaks:

**View:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click To View File", "GetFile", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="ViewFile" })
<pre id='ViewFile'>
</pre>
```

**Controller:**

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
    return File("~/file.txt", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
}
```

Comment: Please remember to mark as answered if it helped you